# Imprimir Array unidimensional en input hidden

Tags: php, html, array

Tengo la variable `$style = [1, 2, 1]`; en `php` y lo que quiero es enviar este `Array` tal cual lo ven aquí, en el `value` de un `input` `hidden` de `HTML`, para así capturarlo en mi controlador y utilizarlo en otras opreaciones.

Lo que requiero es que este `input` `hidden` lleve en su `value` el `Array` tal cual se encuentra (`[1, 2, 1]`), pues cuando lo voy a utilizar en mis operaciones, solo este formato es el que recibe y desafortunadamente todos mis intentos han sido fallidos, pues me imprimen de una manera diferente, les agradecería su ayuda.

```
$style = [1, 2, 1];

<input type="hidden" name="style" id="style" value=<?php $style ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la función *Implode*, que genera un string a partir de los elementos del array recibido

```
<?php

$array = array('apellido', 'email', 'teléfono');
$string = implode(",", $array);

echo '['.$string.']'; // [apellido,email,teléfono]
?>
```

De esta forma envias al controlador y a la vista la cadena tal cual la necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Algo que puedes intentar es serializar el arreglo y enviarlo a traves del input hidden

```
//Input desde el que se envía
$style=[1,2,1];
<input type='hidden' name='style' value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($style)); ?>" />

//Archivo donde se recibe
$passed_array = unserialize($_POST['style']);
```

Otra opción sería usar una sesión y llamarlo desde ahí

```
session_start();
$style=[1,2,1];
$_SESSION['style'] = $style;
```

Una ventaja de usar una sesión es que el cliente no puede ver directamente los datos viendo el código html que muestra el navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez la forma más "adecuada" de pasar un array es por medio de un foreach con varios campos, cuyo name sea el mismo (un array con keys vacios):

```
<?php
$style = [1, 2, 1];

foreach ($style as $value) { ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="style[]" value="<?php echo $value ?>">

<?php } ?>
```

El único "problema" aquí sería que no puedes usar el mismo id para los 3 campos, en caso que lo necesites para algo en tu frontend.

Ya al momento de recibir los datos del formulario, simplemente tomas la variable `$_POST["style"]` y ahí lo tienes formateado como un array normal `[1,2,1]`.

---

Si lo que quieres definitivamente es enviar los valores como un string, entonces una solución es usar implode sobre el array que ya creaste:

```
<?php
$style = [1, 2, 1];

$styleStr = implode(",", $style);
?>

<input type="hidden" name="style" id="style" value="[<?php echo $styleStr ?>]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui la solución:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3018b66baf229d85ce79d691688a21684bc2bc5e

```
<?php

$style = [1, 2, 1];
$arr = "";
$i = 0;

foreach ($style as $val) { 

    if ($i == 0) {
        $arr =  $val;
    } else {
        $arr = $arr . "," . $val;
    }

    $i++;

}

?>

<input type="hidden" name="style" id="style" value="<?php print([".$arr."]"); ?>"/>
```

Saludos...